# Generating arrivals and average waiting time

Tags: java

I'm a little confused when creating a simulation for a bus line.

The problem is that the bus travels from one station to another for a period of time. Once it goes from Station 1 to Station 2, it will load some passengers at Station 2.

My problem is since that I want to generate some passengers at Station 2 for the time the station was idle(last bus left till new buss arrived) I was thinking of using a Poisson Process with a lambda for the arrivals and the time period.

From another StackOverflow post I found a function to compute PoissonArrivals given the mean, but how can I introduce the time constraint in it?

```
public static int getPoissonRandom(double mean) {
        Random r = new Random();
        double L = Math.exp(-mean);
        int k = 0;
        double p = 1.0;
        do {
            p = p * r.nextDouble();
            k++;
        } while (p > L);
        return k - 1;
    }
```

I'm asking because since this is Discrete event simulation, I can't have my model look in the past every time, so for every station I store the last departure time. I also think that a good quality measure will be the avg waiting time (Sum of passenger waiting times till they board the next bus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.UniformRealDistribution;
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.PoissonDistribution;
public class PassengerArrivals {

    private double T, lambda; // Time interval
    private double waiting;

    public PassengerArrivals(double lambda, double timeInterval) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.lambda = lambda;
        this.T = timeInterval;
        this.avg_waiting = 0;


        // Generate the number of events that will occur
        PoissonDistribution pd = new PoissonDistribution(this.lambda);
        int n = pd.sample();

        // Initialize an array to store the arrival times t_i, i = {1,2,..., n}.
        double arrivals[] = new double[n];

        // Generate the arrival times through a U[0,T]
        UniformRealDistribution ud = new UniformRealDistribution(0, this.T);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            arrivals[i] = ud.sample();
        }

        //The Waiting times between events will be independent and identically distributed exponentialy.
        double sum_waiting_time = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            // For me, the waiting time is the time the arrival of passenger occurred and he will wait until the time interval will be done.
            sum_waiting_time += timeInterval - arrivals[i];
        }

        // Sometimes I got a NaN, possibly because my lambda was small so no events were generated. So it doesn't hurt to check :P
        if (Double.isNaN(waiting_time)) {
            sum_waiting_time = 0;
        }

        this.avg_waiting = sum_waiting_time / n;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public double getAvgWaitingTime() {
        return this.waiting;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the simulation of how many people will board the current bus at `Station 2`, you need to define two things:

- p = the average of number of people arriving at `Station 2` per hour;
- d = How much time passed (in hours) between both buses passing, i.e. since the last bus left until the current bus is leaving.

Now the mean is simply:

```
mean = p*d
```

You will now calculate `getPoissonRandom(mean)` and this will give you the number of people getting on the bus.

Note that the function is not deterministic; The idea is that it gives a number following the distribution of probabilities as given by the Poisson distribution.

**Example**

For example, say that `p=5` (average of 5 people per hour), and the time between buses was `d=0.5` (half an hour). You would run the simulation with `getPoissonRandom(2.5)`.

Comment: But, how will I be able to compute the average waiting time with this approach?